# How to setup a single post page for my custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

This my Custom Post Type Code

```
/* Job Opening */
add_action( 'init', 'create_job_opening' );
function create_job_opening() {
    register_post_type( 'job_opening',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Job Opening',
                'singular_name' => 'Job Opening',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Job Opening',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Job Opening',
                'new_item' => 'New job opening',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View job opening',
                'search_items' => 'Search job opening',
                'not_found' => 'No Job Opening found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Job Opening found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent job opening'
            ),

            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/Careerpost-icon.png',  // Icon Path
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin_job' );

function my_admin_job() {
    add_meta_box( 'job_opening_meta_box',
        'job Details',
        'display_job_opening_meta_box',
        'job_opening', 'normal', 'high'
    );
}
```

I can call my post to sidebar

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'job_opening', 'posts_per_page' => 30 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;
```

my `single.php` is blank now. how can i create a `job-single-post.php`
how to specify `job-single-post.php` is the single post template for job_opening CPT?.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress uses a naming pattern that determines what template gets used to display a certain kind of content.

In your case, all you need to do is create a template file with a standard loop and name it single-job_opening.php. This will ensure that this file gets loaded when the user views a single job opening post. You can find out more about this here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

I recommend that you use the Debug Bar Plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) when running into similar problems in the future. Not only will it tell what template is loaded on what page, but it also gives you an indication of what content type is loaded.